# Cannot find module 'iap_verifier'

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I`m installing this server - https://github.com/surespot/web-server. I installed node.js, npm, CoffeScript and all dependencies

```
apt-get install nodejs npm
npm install -g coffee-script@1.6.3
npm install
```

When I execute command `coffee server/cluster.coffee`, I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'iap_verifier'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/web-server/server/cluster.coffee:35:15, <js>:64:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/web-server/server/cluster.coffee:1:1, <js>:4482:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

but module files exist in `node_modules` dir.

I also try manualy install module

```
npm install iap_verifier
```

and

```
npm install iap_verifier -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you required the module in the main app.js file and try running `sudo npm install iap_verifier -g`

Comment: In `cluster.coffee` file the is line `IAPVerifier = require 'iap_verifier'`
`.

Comment: I`m working from root, maybe therefore error occuries?

Comment: The app file can not find the module location. By default this is the root directory. Make sure you installed the required modules, and then make sure the main app.js file is in the same folder as the node modules.